# jQuery button widget not working properly on submit in Chrome

Tags: jquery, forms, button, user-interface, dialog

I have one little problem with my web. I have there form in external file, something like below.

```
<form action="/action.php" method="post" id="formularz_dodaj" target="iframe_id">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="groups_save" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                Some fields here
            </li>
            <li class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" class="zapisz" value="Zapisz" />
                <input type="button" class="anuluj" value="Anuluj" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $j('.zapisz').button().click(function(){
        $j('.anuluj').hide();
    });
    $j('.anuluj').button().click(function(){
        $j('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

As You can see, there is nothing special about it except buttons. As a result form gets styled buttons via jQuery. Button `<input type="submit" class="zapisz" value="Zapisz" />` should work as normal submit, `<input type="button" class="anuluj" value="Anuluj" />` should just clos the dialog.
This form is placed in dialog via jQuery ajax() method like so:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
var main = new Object();

$j.extend($j.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
modal: true,
resizable: false,
width:'auto',
height:'auto',
show:{
    effect:'fade',
    duration:'fast'
},
hide:{
    effect:'fade',
    duration:'fast'
},
open:function(){
    $j(this).find("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=checkbox],     select, textarea").uniform();
}
});
main.dialog = function(ob){
if(ob.url){
    var url = arguments.url;
    var dialog = $j("#dialog");
    if ($j("#dialog").length == 0) {
        dialog = $j('<div id="dialog" class="dialog" title=""></div>').appendTo('body');
    }
    if(ob.title){
        dialog.attr('title', ob.title);
    }
    $j.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        data:ob.dane,
        url:ob.url,
        success:function(d){
            if(d == 'uprawnienia'){
                main.alert({
                    text:'Nie posiadasz uprawnie\u0144 do tej operacji.', 
                    title:'Brak uprawnie\u0144'
                });
            } else {
                $j("#dialog").html(d);
                $j("#dialog").dialog({
                    title:$j("#dialog").attr('title')
                });
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Niepoprawne rz\u0105danie.');
        }
    });
} else {
   alert('Brak pliku do za\u0142adowania.');
}
}
```

The target for data is an iframe placed in main index file.

```
<iframe name="iframe_id" id="iframe_id" src="" style="display:none; width:400px; height:200px;"></iframe>
```

What happens is when i use button with class ".zapisz" nothing happens in specific browsers: IE8, Chrome, Safari. In IE9 and FireFox it's working as it should.

I've checked the console in any of my browsers and there is no error. No data from form is sended to iframe. Only JS added in click method is executed.

Button ".zapisz" works as they should only when `document.getElemntById('formularz_dodaj').submit();` is written in click function.

Anyone have idea what can be wrong?

Comment: _"nothing happens in specific browsers"_ - Do you mean something _does_ happen in other browsers (e.g., Firefox or newer IE)?

Comment: How are you defining `$j`, try just `$`. Also, sharing your CSS would help.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question, but you also missing a `<ul>` tag. You close your ul without open it first. At least in code you provide

Comment: By "form is not submitted", what do you mean? Is the browser going to to `action.php`?

Comment: Yes, in FireFox and IE8 all works as expected: form is submited after clicking "zapisz". `code`$j is simply defined as: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`code`

Comment: @pbaris Yes, my bad, but only in this example code

Comment: What exactly happens in Chrome? Is the next page loaded? Have you tried my updated code?

Comment: @ATOzTOA there is no data sended. I've chaecked this via console besides no effect on page ofcourse.

Comment: So, is the page redirected to `action.php`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA after click on button only JS assigned via jQuery is applied and there no actual submit is done.

Comment: OK, try my code now and see if the alert is showing.

Comment: What is the path where your "action.php" is located?

Comment: @ATOzTOA in this case there is an issue with sending data, path to php in "action" has nothing to do with this problem :)

Comment: Which browser are you trying on now?

Comment: @ATOzTOA i'm using Firefox 17 basicly (occasionally i check my systems in IE8, IE9, Safari 5, Opera 12, Chrome 23)

Comment: OK, so which browser is it NOT working on now?

Comment: IE 8, Safari 5, Opera 12, Chrome 23

Comment: I've edited my example, maybe it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there was no solution or pointed cause of such behavior I founded some workaround solution. Because all dialog (in my case) contain buttons witch classes `.zapisz` and/or `.anuluj` and usage of them is identical in each case i predefined such code:

```
$j.extend($j.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto',
    show:{
        effect:'fade',
        duration:'fast'
    },
    hide:{
        effect:'fade',
        duration:'fast'
    },
    open:function(){
        $j(this).find("input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=checkbox], select, textarea").uniform();
        $j(this).find('input[type=submit], input[type=button]').button();
        $j(this).find('.zapisz').each(function(){
            $j(this).click(function(){
                $j(this).parents('form').submit();
                $j(this).parents('form').find('.ui-state-error').hide();
            });
        });
        $j(this).find('.anuluj').each(function(){
            $j(this).click(function(){
                $j(this).parents('.dialog').dialog('close');
            });
        });
        $j('.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick').on('click', function(){
            $j(this).parent().parent().hide();
        });
        $j(this).find('.ui-state-error').hide();
        $j('span.opis').tooltip();
    }
});
```

What this code does is (omitting basic settings like effects etc.) when dialog is opened it searches for buttons with thosw classes `.zapisz` and/or `.anuluj` and gives them a proper action according to parent. So now there is no need to add `submit()` to every form i have manualy.

Next thing is when i need to add some other actions to any of those button i simply write them in form itself just like that:

```
$j('.zapisz').click(function(){
    $j('.anuluj').hide();
    $j(this).val('Wysy\u0142am dane');
    $j(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Notice that there is no longer `button()` method before adding `click()`.

Now i have dialogs that are formated as i wanted and works as expected by default.

Still i have no idea why my issue happens in some browsers, so if You will have any information about that it would be nice for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside

```
$(function(){
//your code here
});
```

and it should work!

If still it does not work remove .button() and try

```
$(function(){
    $j('.zapisz').click(function(){
        $j('.anuluj').hide();
    });
    $j('.anuluj').click(function(){
        $j('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

Comment: OP already have the JS after the form, so the form is already loaded.

Comment: Nope. Still the same lack of submitting the form. With button() or witout it those behave the same: form isn't submited.

Comment: replace                 <input type="button" class="anuluj" value="Anuluj" />
with                 <input type="submit" class="anuluj" value="Anuluj" />

Comment: @Rohit Patel sorry but that makes no sense. "Anuluj" should only close the dialog not sending data from form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $j('.zapisz').click(function(){
        $j('.anuluj').hide();
    });
    $j('.anuluj').click(function(){
        $j('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

Regards.

Comment: Still nothig. As i sad: JS assigned to button works just fine (like this hide() method). What is all about that in some browsers i need to add to styled submit button submit() method.

Comment: The code is already below the form, so no need for `ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

is see that the target of the form is `target="iframe_id"`. Do you have any iframe in your page that is hidden, so the submit is done but you cannot 'see' it.

The answer that @ATOzTOA gave is working just fine but it opens in new tab. So maybe there is a hidden iframe in your page and the form targets that

**Edit**

You iframe has name and id `upload` but your target in form is `iframe_id`. try change your form as

```
<form action="/action.php" method="post" id="formularz_dodaj" target="upload">
```

Comment: exactly, there is an iframe where all the work should be done. You gave mi some clue. After typing `code $j('iframe_id');` i Firefox console it returns an object (as expected) but in chrome same operation returns NULL and propably this is the issue. I've no idea what to do about it next.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Chrome selects iframe as it should.

Comment: May it be the problem that dialog is "modal" and iframe is in index file not in dialog itself?

Comment: That was copy of a original code, in example form i;v changed it for better uderstanding (i'll fix that). In my oryginal code ID's used in form and iframe are the same.

Answer (score -1):

One catch: `/action.php` will try to load `action.php` located in the root of your filesystem. You should use `./action.php`.

This is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE6:

```
<form action="./action.php" method="post" id="formularz_dodaj" onsubmit="alert('Submitting form');" target="iframe_id">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="groups_save" />
        <ul>
            <li>
                Some fields here
            </li>
            <li class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" class="zapisz" value="Zapisz" />
                <input type="button" class="anuluj" value="Anuluj" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.zapisz').click(function(){
        $('.anuluj').hide();
        return true;
    });

    $('.anuluj').click(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. Button is set to type="submit". But i tryed anyway: still no difference.

Comment: No alert is shown. I'm using paths relative to ROOT of my page so that isn't a problem. There is no data sended so there is even an error like 404.

Comment: Are you saying there is 404 error? Can you put your current code into a jsFiddle?